# NodeJS MongoDB cursor toArray callback function doesn't make changes on parent scope variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, scope, callback

```
MongoClient.connect(dburl, function (err, db) {
   var collections = [];
   db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, collInfos) {
       for (var i = 0; i < collInfos.length; i++) {
           collections[i] = collInfos[i].name;
       }
       console.log(collections);
   });
   console.log(collections);
});
```

So I want to get all my database collections into an array of strings and this is a piece of my code.

The problem is that the `console.log` outside of the `toArray` callback gets executed first and outputs `[]`, whereas the `console.log` inside the `toArray` callback outputs the array properly.

It seems to me there is some kind of scope problem but I am not familiar with how NodeJS and MongoDB exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This portion of the code is asynchronous:

```
db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, collInfos) {
  for (var i = 0; i < collInfos.length; i++) {
    collections[i] = collInfos[i].name;
  }
  console.log(collections);
});
```

So it will execute after your second call to `console.log(collections)`, which is why you see an empty array `[]` first and then a populated list of collections. It's not a scope problem but a confusion about synchronous vs asynchronous function call order.

If I were you, I would ditch the callback pattern and instead use promises. Then you can do something like this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var Collection = mongodb.Collection;

Promise.promisifyAll(Collection.prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(MongoClient);

var client = MongoClient.connectAsync('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
    .then(function(db) {
        return db.collection("myCollection").findOneAsync({ id: 'someId' })
    })
    .then(function(item) {
      // Use `item`
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // An error occurred
    });
```

Hope this helps!